# Maxim MCU & Eclipse and OpenOCD

Tags: eclipse, openocd, cmsis

I have a fresh install of Maxims Micros SDK and I am having an issue when I try to debug or even run on target. I get the following output

```
    Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-g4f85f7914 (2021-12-16-13:53)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter driver' not 'interface'
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter srst delay' not 'adapter_nsrst_delay'
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter srst pulse_width' not 'adapter_nsrst_assert_width'
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

This was not the issue a few weeks ago, I now have a fresh windows install. When I plug the MCU i get the DAPLINK removable drive pop up for drag-drop firmware but cmsis_dap debugging seems to not be working at least thats what I can gather, or somehow openocd version is too new than what the script in eclipse was written for.
This is what eclipse script for debug and run configurations has:

```
-s ${env_var:TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/OpenOCD/scripts -f  interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/max32670.cfg
```